# Possible bug found for SSG due to Next 14 server caching behaviour

Tags: caching, next.js, app-router, static-site-generation, react-server-components

I am programming a chef webpage that needs internationalization, so I am using SSG to prerender all pages for each locale.
I am finding problems in build time while trying to build server or page components that fetch data from my backend, this problems are only there if the data from the backend is cached, if I opt-out caching or dont use SSG or simply just run dev mode there is no problems, but caching behaviour is blocking the database requests and always gets me a MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations...
I checked it already and  it is not a db problem, because as I said if I opt out from caching there is no issues at all and all runs as expected. The problem is then that every data fetch from the server would be dinamically rendered and cache is then useless. Any one has an idea about what is happening?:lolsob:

This is the code from the Menu page in the app directory, the SSG locale is being set at main layout level.

```
import { getAllProducts } from '@/database/dbProducts';
import XDraggableList from '../XDraggableList';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';
import { IMenuItem } from '@/interfaces/IMenuItem';

const Menu = async () => {
  
const products: IMenuItem[] = await getAllProducts();

  .... rest of the code
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

This is the code getting the data from the database:

```
import { db } from '.';
import { IMenuItem } from '@/interfaces/IMenuItem';
import Product from '@/models/Product';
import { unstable_noStore } from 'next/cache';

export const getAllProducts = async (): Promise<IMenuItem[]> => {
  //TODO: why is the error at build time when caching is not opt out
  //unstable_noStore();
  //if the unstable_noStore() option is not used I get the build time error
  //MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
  //the problem with having to opt-out the caching behaviour is that then the request
  //is always reaching the database

  await db.connect();
  const products = await Product.find().sort({ name: 1 }).lean();
  await db.disconnect();

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
};
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next build
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.3
   - Environments: .env

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data    
   Generating static pages (24/32) [  ==]
Connected to MongoDb:
MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
    at executeOperationAsync (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:23:19)
    at C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:45
    at maybeCallback (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:269:21)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:38)
    at FindCursor._initialize (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\find_cursor.js:55:73)
    at [kInit] (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:450:38)
    at next (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:510:32)
    at FindCursor.next (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:226:16)
    at [Symbol.asyncIterator] (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:160:45)
    at AsyncGenerator.next (<anonymous>) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

This error repeats 7 times and then comes this other one:

```
Generating static pages (24/32) [   =]
Connected to MongoDb:
   Generating static pages (24/32) [  ==]
Connected to MongoDb:
   Generating static pages (24/32) [ ===]
Connected to MongoDb:
Connected to MongoDb:
Disconnnected from MongoDb

Error occurred prerendering page "/de/menu". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
    at executeOperationAsync (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:23:19)
    at C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:45
    at maybeCallback (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:269:21)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:38)
    at FindCursor._initialize (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\find_cursor.js:55:73)
    at [kInit] (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:450:38)
    at next (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:510:32)
    at FindCursor.next (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:226:16)
    at [Symbol.asyncIterator] (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:160:45)
    at AsyncGenerator.next (<anonymous>)
Disconnnected from MongoDb
Disconnnected from MongoDb

Error occurred prerendering page "/es/menu". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
    at executeOperationAsync (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:23:19)
    at C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:45
    at maybeCallback (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:269:21)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:38)
    at FindCursor._initialize (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\find_cursor.js:55:73)
    at [kInit] (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:450:38)
    at next (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:510:32)
    at FindCursor.next (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:226:16)
    at [Symbol.asyncIterator] (C:\Users\pcjos\Desktop\Proyectos\Ingrid\shadcn-ingrid-webpage\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor\abstract_cursor.js:160:45)
    at AsyncGenerator.next (<anonymous>)
```

And so on for the rest of locales...
Does anyone has an idea of what is happening?

I tried opting out caching for the data fetching and it is working, the problem then is that it makes SSG useless as I am always regenerating the page with new data from my database.

Comment: If you suspect that this is a bug, rather create a [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues) in the Next.js repository than asking the question here as there is no real answer to be given.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

> 'force-dynamic': Force dynamic rendering, which will result in routes being rendered for each user at request time. This option is equivalent to getServerSideProps() in the pages directory.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic